# How to solve "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, shutil

I have 2 files to copy from a folder to another folder and these are my codes:

```
import shutil

src = '/Users/cadellteng/Desktop/Program Booklet/'
dst = '/Users/cadellteng/Desktop/Python/'
file = ['AI+Product+Manager+Nanodegree+Program+Syllabus.pdf','Artificial+Intelligence+with+Python+Nanodegree+Syllabus+9-5.pdf']

for i in file:
    shutil.copyfile(src+file[i], dst+file[i])
```

When I tried to run the code I got the following error message:

```
/Users/cadellteng/venv/bin/python /Users/cadellteng/PycharmProjects/someProject/movingFiles.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cadellteng/PycharmProjects/someProject/movingFiles.py", line 8, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(src+file[i], dst+file[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to find some solution on stackoverflow and one thread suggest to do this:

```
for i in range(file):
    shutil.copyfile(src+file[i], dst+file[i])
```

and then I got the following error message:

```
/Users/cadellteng/venv/bin/python /Users/cadellteng/PycharmProjects/someProject/movingFiles.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cadellteng/PycharmProjects/someProject/movingFiles.py", line 7, in <module>
    for i in range(file):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So now I am thoroughly confused. If "i" can't be a string and it can't be an integer, what should it be?
I am using PyCharm CE and very new to Python.

Comment: `for i in file` gives you `i` as an element in file list, not an index, so it will change to `shutil.copyfile(src+i, dst+i)`, or if you want indexes, you need to do `for i in range(len(file))` and then you can use  `shutil.copyfile(src+file[i], dst+file[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the below code since `i` doesn't need an extra indexing `file[...]`, because it is not an index:

```
for i in file:
    shutil.copyfile(src + i, dst + i)
```

If you want to use `range`, use it this way with `len`:

```
for i in range(len(file)):
    shutil.copyfile(src+file[i], dst+file[i])
```

But of course the first solution is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. I do prefer the first solution. Cheers~

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below, and read [for Statement in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

```
import shutil

src = '/Users/cadellteng/Desktop/Program Booklet/'
dst = '/Users/cadellteng/Desktop/Python/'
file = ['AI+Product+Manager+Nanodegree+Program+Syllabus.pdf','Artificial+Intelligence+with+Python+Nanodegree+Syllabus+9-5.pdf']

for i in file:
    shutil.copyfile(src + i, dst + i)
```